# How to Perform ToString On Property of an Entity Framework Model Using Reflection

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, reflection

I am trying to write something that will do a "Contains" query on all properties of an entity framework model.

I am able to do the following for example with no issues:

```
var students = db.Students.AsQueryable();
var test = students.Where(x => x.FirstName.ToString().ToLower().Contains("1"));
```

However when using reflection (as shown in the code below), the following error is returned:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

It's supposed to be [supported](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2327346-support-tostring-method-in-linq-to-entities) now.

I have read up on this error, **but as you see above ToString is perfectly valid even when using an IQueryable** (which is required in my case because I don't want to post filter the data).

The main difference is I need to invoke it through reflection.

```
private static readonly MethodInfo StringContainsMethod =
    typeof(string).GetMethod(@"Contains",
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { typeof(string) }, null);

Type dbType = typeof(Student);

var dbFieldMemberInfo = dbType.GetMember("FirstName",
BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Single();          

// Create an "x" as TDbType
var dbTypeParameter = Expression.Parameter(dbType, @"x");

// Get at x.FirstName
var dbFieldMember = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(dbTypeParameter, dbFieldMemberInfo);         

// Create the criterion as a constant
var criterionConstant = new Expression[] { Expression.Constant(searchString) };          

var toStringMethod = typeof(Convert).GetMethod("ToString", Type.EmptyTypes);
var toStringCall = Expression.Call(dbFieldMember, toStringMethod);
var fancyContain = Expression.Call(toStringCall, StringContainsMethod, criterionConstant);

// Create a lambda like x => x.FirstName.ToString().Contains(criterion)
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(fancyContain, dbTypeParameter) as Expression<Func<Student, bool>>;
```

This produces the same exact lambda `x.FirstName.ToString().Contains("")` yet it returns an error that ToString can't be used. Clearly from the first example and the fact it was added to EF 6.1, it can be used. Is this a limitation of reflection?

Comment: I would say if you are using EF to query your db metadata using string matching, you are defeating the purpose of EF and should pursue a different solution. The datacontext isn't intended to be used to query metadata. If you are dead-set on this, then either push it up or down a layer instead of trying to make it translate into a query. EIther do some string magic on your model properties and then write an expression to include only those properties in your query, or go down a layer and create a stored proc or have the context execute a query directly.

Comment: This is a generic solution. Basically someone has a datagrid... They have a single search box... They can type a number or some text into the search box and it will automatically do a server side search against all fields in the entity that they have marked as searchable. If the field happens to be an int field I need to use ToString on it. It allows someone to easily query against all their fields without doing any setup or manual case statements.

Comment: Also I can easily detect if the properties are strings, but I want to also support integer fields without using equals. If I type 10 for instance, that number 10 can occur anywhere in the numeric field and thus must be parsed as a string. It might also for instance search a date field, etc. It's not meant to be a lightening fast searching solution, just a way to plug and play search on a data grid.

Comment: this is probably an issue with `Func<T>` vs. `Expression<Func<T>>`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean... In both cases it is using Expression<Func... The first code sample I have... the where accepts an Expression<Func...

Comment: Can you post how you are using the lambda?

Comment: it's in the second code example. Just pretend that "FirstName" is passed in dynamically. I need to convert that string to something like (x => x.FirstName.ToString().Contains("mysearchstring") >> Which the second snippet does successfully, although when I execute it I get the ToString error even though EF properly creates the SQL and subsequent string cast when I just invoke it directly (as shown in the first code sample).

Comment: The last line would be students.Where(lambda). I see what you are asking now.

Comment: No, I mean, are you calling `students.Where(lambda)` or compiling the expression first, or what?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://www.entityframework.info/Home/FullTextSearch

Comment: I noticed you're creating an expression using the `Convert.ToString()` method and having your variable call that method. That's a bit different than the usage in the link you posted (`e.Id.ToString()`) which is the individual type's implementation of `ToString()`. You may need to get the type of the parameter and then call *that* `ToString()` method.

Comment: I think you are right! I tried using Convert.ToString on my original query and that doesn't work either. I will give that a shot.

Comment: Made my day. Ten thumbs up. If you want to post your comment as answer, I will mark as answer. I was able to do this:   Type type = ((PropertyInfo)dbFieldMemberInfo).PropertyType and then type.GetMethod("ToString", Type.EmptyTypes); Bingo!

Comment: Rarely I find people to stick with me this long on an issue. Thanks so much seriously.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. I'll go ahead and write up an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the issue is stemming from using the `Convert.ToString()` method in your expression instead of the type's individual implementation of the `ToString()` method, e.g. `toStringMethod = type.GetMethod("ToString", Type.EmptyTypes);`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you trying to do is to search based on all columns the easiest and fastest way would be to execute query from EF and do full text search.

```
 var students = db.Database.SqlQuery<Student>("SELECT * FROM Student WHERE CONTAINS((Name, ID), '12')");
```

(just make sure you clean the string no sql injections)

I think that when you build the expression tree as you trying to do and execute it against SQL, SQL does not recognizing it because when you use Querable you not yet executing it.

another way is to use `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` instead of `ToString`

Comment: Thanks, although this is for a common library that other people will use. I think the risk of sql injection is too high and I am not sure how to eliminate it 100% without parameter queries. Basically I am allowing people to hook up a datatables.net grid and automatically search on whatever entity they are using.

Comment: Also I have read about the SqlFunctions.StringConvert, but I am not sure how this explains why my first code sample works. It seems to fail when trying to invoke the methods through reflection. In both cases I use IQueryable. The first example produces sql code that does a cast to nvarchar, then a ToLower, etc. and works fine.

Comment: I updated my code sample and title to make it a little more clear.

Comment: @KingOfHypocrites you can use parameters with this method.

Comment: Thanks, I may go that route if need be, but I have code working already that doesn't require dynamic sql statements and is completely generic. Calling ToString using reflection is the only thing that isn't working.

Comment: I use reflection to access the property of the model using a string. I take the string "FirstName" and then I am able to use that to build a reference to the first name property. You talk about using Convert.ToString, but I am already doing that: var toStringMethod = typeof(Convert).GetMethod("ToString", Type.EmptyTypes);

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a lot of complexity for something that should be fairly simple. I would suggest making a `textdata` computed column in your table that simply concatenates all the fields you're interested in. Then you can add a property to your model like this:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public string TextData { get; set; }
```

Finally, you can just do a LINQ query against this one property to check whether it `.Contains(...)` whatever text you're interested in. As long as you index the column, searching shouldn't be too bad. Your major penalty will be in inserts.

Comment: Thanks, although this is a common library used by others so I have no control over their database structure.